# jQuery automatically fade in div and fade out on scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I am a little new to JQuery and I am trying to make a div at the bottom of the page fade in when the page loads and then when a user starts to scroll the div needs to fade out and then reappear when scrolling back to the top.

The code I have done just to fade the div in isn't working and can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/DeZnT/

The jQuery I am using is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function(){
         $(".other_product_links").animate({bottom:'0px'});
      });
});
```

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

Comment: Try `$(".other_product_links").fadeIn(1000);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fade in (There's also a corresponding fadeOut method):

```
$("#element").fadeIn(300);
```

For detecting how far down a user has scrolled, you can use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var posFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(posFromTop > 200){
        // if more than 200px from the top do something


        } else {
        // otherwise do something else.

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to remove the display:none from your class, and set the bottom position to start below the page (which is 0 minus the div height).

```css
.other_product_links {
  height: 200px;
  width:100%;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: #ffd6fd;
  border-top: 2px solid #f095d9;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -200px;
```

}

Then, all your jQuery needs to do is move the bottom to 0.

```js
$(".other_product_links").animate({bottom: '0px'}, 1000);
```

That gets you half-way. I've not done the scrolling part before.