# Fade out div when scrolling down (in relation to scroll)

Tags: html, css, fade

I have an intro screen which is 100% height and width.

I'd like to start it off with an opacity of 1, and when the user scrolls down the opacity generally decreases until the bottom of the div is about 100px away from the top - this is when the opacity should reach 0.

Any suggestions? Been looking for a solution and havent found anything.

Can you do this in CSS3?

This is my HTML & CSS so far

HTML

```
<div class="outer" id="welcome">
<div class="inner">
<p>Hi Hello Hi Hello Hi Hello</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
    display:table;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.inner {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}

.content {
height:1000px;
background-color:pink;
}
```

Comment: Can you recommend a plug in?

Comment: Check the total scrolled distance, and give the element an opacity of `distance/(element height - 100)`

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047493/jquery-automatically-fade-in-div-and-fade-out-on-scroll) might be what you need. Uses Jquery.